# Autocomplete textbox with JSON datasource

Tags: javascript, json, google-app-engine, autocomplete

I'm trying to create an autocomplete textbox that uses a JSON file as its datasource, but have not been able to do so. The app resides on Google App Engine and the current autocomplete datasource is an array of countries entered into the code, but I'd rather use a remote datasource that's in JSON format. Also, the JSON file will have additional name/value pairings such as "country":"USA", "capitol":"DC","continent":"NorthAmerica", etc.

Does anyone know how I can do that? Does it make more sense to take the JSON data and put it into a database like Google Datastore?

Below is the code I'm using with the local array. Thanks!

```js
var countries = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua &amp; Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","British Virgin Islands","Brunei","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cambodia","Cameroon","Canada","Cape Verde","Cayman Islands","Central Arfrican Republic","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Congo","Cook Islands","Costa Rica","Cote D Ivoire","Croatia","Cuba","Curacao","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea","Eritrea","Estonia","Ethiopia","Falkland Islands","Faroe Islands","Fiji","Finland","France","French Polynesia","French West Indies","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana","Gibraltar","Greece","Greenland","Grenada","Guam","Guatemala","Guernsey","Guinea","Guinea Bissau","Guyana","Haiti","Honduras","Hong Kong","Hungary","Iceland","India","Indonesia","Iran","Iraq","Ireland","Isle of Man","Israel","Italy","Jamaica","Japan","Jersey","Jordan","Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kiribati","Kosovo","Kuwait","Kyrgyzstan","Laos","Latvia","Lebanon","Lesotho","Liberia","Libya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Macau","Macedonia","Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Marshall Islands","Mauritania","Mauritius","Mexico","Micronesia","Moldova","Monaco","Mongolia","Montenegro","Montserrat","Morocco","Mozambique","Myanmar","Namibia","Nauro","Nepal","Netherlands","Netherlands Antilles","New Caledonia","New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger","Nigeria","North Korea","Norway","Oman","Pakistan","Palau","Palestine","Panama","Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Poland","Portugal","Puerto Rico","Qatar","Reunion","Romania","Russia","Rwanda","Saint Pierre &amp; Miquelon","Samoa","San Marino","Sao Tome and Principe","Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","Solomon Islands","Somalia","South Africa","South Korea","South Sudan","Spain","Sri Lanka","St Kitts &amp; Nevis","St Lucia","St Vincent","Sudan","Suriname","Swaziland","Sweden","Switzerland","Syria","Taiwan","Tajikistan","Tanzania","Thailand","Timor L'Este","Togo","Tonga","Trinidad &amp; Tobago","Tunisia","Turkey","Turkmenistan","Turks &amp; Caicos","Tuvalu","Uganda","Ukraine","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","United States of America","Uruguay","Uzbekistan","Vanuatu","Vatican City","Venezuela","Vietnam","Virgin Islands (US)","Yemen","Zambia","Zimbabwe"];
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
body {
  font: 16px Arial; 
}
.autocomplete {
  /*the container must be positioned relative:*/
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
input {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
input[type=text] {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}
input[type=submit] {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: #fff;
}
.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4; 
}
.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  /*when hovering an item:*/
  background-color: #e9e9e9; 
}
.autocomplete-active {
  /*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important; 
  color: #ffffff; 
}
```

```html
<!--Make sure the form has the autocomplete function switched off:-->
<form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

Comment: _...Does it make more sense to take the JSON data and put it into a
database like Google Datastore?_ This is not a particular use case for Datastore according to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview#what_its_good_for) For the data you have, it doesn't make sense to have it stored in a separate service either. If your data grows too large and you want to have it stored somewhere, try [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you ask 2 questions :

***1) How to add an autocomplete feature to your site/app :***

As it was mentionned in comments, you can try some JS components, as jQuery autocomplete.
This kind of components request a JSON file to be reachable via an URL address.

***2) Where to host JSON file or How to serve JSON file ?***

You can put JSON file on Google Storage Bucket, with public sharing. You will be able to upload a new version when you want without need to redeploy app.
Your file stored in a GS Bucket is reachable via http URL.
So perfect for your JS component.